# How to run jQuery's .on( "change", handler ) for the last element in collection which was created dynamically through another jQuery code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to run jQuery on the last element of a specific class that is dynamically generated.

Classically I would use:

```
    $(".class").last().on("change", function(){
       something();
    });
```

but since the `.class` element is generated through jQuery after the page is rendered, I have to use:

```
$("body").on("change", ".class", function(){
  something();
});
```

but this entry causes the change in the first (or any) element on the page to trigger the event.

I would need to somehow include the `.last()` function into the second selector.

Simply: I have an input on the page that is empty, when a change is made to it, a copy of this input with empty content should be generated and inserted after the first input. If this one is filled, another one is generated.
Currently (using $("body").on("change",...) the next input is generated again and again even if I change the first input field X times.

Thanks everyone

Comment: How simple :D even though the selector is marked as obsolete. Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _Because :last is a (deprecated) jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :last cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()_

Answer (score 2):

You can ask

```
$("body").on("change", ".class", function(){
  if($(this).is(':last-child')) {
    //something
  }
});
```